# clickhouse：SYSTEM STOP MERGES does not work

Tags: merge, clickhouse

In factally，I want to use [SYSTEM STOP MERGES TABLE](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/system/#query_language-system-stop-merges) to stop merge and then migrate some parts to another shard. My operation as follow:

1.

```sh
clickhouse-client -q "insert into DTDB.lineorder_demo FORMAT CSV" < lineorder.tbl；
```

2. I execute

```sql
SYSTEM STOP MERGES DTDB.lineorder_demo
```

immediately after the import is complete. But within 15 minutes, the parts will still merge and decrease.

Comment: Because `stop merges` is not applicable to Distributed Engine

Comment: @DennyCrane It s has nothing to do with Distributed Engine, old_parts_lifetime causes expired parts to be deleted after 8 minutes.